# PayPal Rest API (PHP SDK) webhooks not showing up in sandbox events list

Tags: php, api, paypal, sdk, paypal-webhooks

When using the webhooks simulator, I get: Got Http response code 500 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-6W4482673W002281V-61985753LP2332451

JSon info is being sent back to my site and I can parse it, but when trying to validate (validateAndGetReceivedEvent) - I get the above 500 error.

Also - when I try submitting an actual sandbox sale, the success return url shows me the sale went through, but a hook is never triggered. (I created a hook that has all events checked)

When I trace with error logs along the way (FYI -I use Codeigniter and I don't have the greatest debugging skills), things seems to come to a stop in PapPalRestCall->Execute 
 $connection = new PayPalHttpConnection($httpConfig, $config);

Answer (score 0):

The event samples which you get from Simulator are sample payloads and does not correspond to actual transactions. If you try to fetch an event from sample payload, you won't be able to retrieve that.

```
{
  "name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
  "details": [],
  "message": "Internal service error"
}
```

This is correct and expected behavior. [You may refer to this Response for Sample Webhook Event Retrieval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPXO3.png)